# App Store Optimization - Special Characters on Keywords of Apple Store

Tags: ios, optimization, indexing, analytics, app-store-connect

I'm submitting an app to Itunes Store, and I want to optimize keyword's use.

I know that, for example, it's not necessary to put both plural and singular words, because Apple treats it if I just put the singular word.

But what about words with special characteres? For example, if I want to use the word "**coração**" as a keyword, and considering that many people will probably search in the Itunes for the word "**coracao**" (whithout the accents in 'c' and 'a') because it's simplier to type, should I put both words in the keywords field? Or just "**coracao**" ? Or just "**coração**", that is the correct one?

PS: I didn't find the proper tags for this question...

Answer (score 2):

Apple App Store isn't accent sensitive, which means: `no, you don't need to put both of the keywords`. I made a search using both of the keywords in [mobileaction dashboard](http://mobileaction.co) and you can see everything is the same for the keywords except search score, for your reference here is screenshot:

[image]

Comment: They do rank other special characters differently though. For example `#randomWord` produces different results than `randomWord`.

Answer (score 0):

Intriguing question. With the example, for me, it depends on your app marketing strategies.

Both is the same and feels redundant to both app keywords as they have almost the same results. But adding a targetted keywords can help you rank on locally, it is only viable if you are targeting LOCALLY.

On the other hand, app store search engines aren't really that good detecting special characters.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to choose both of it as keywords. It is a waste of characters. Just as upstairs said, if you want your app only in your country, you can choose "coração" as your keywords, if you want to make your app in multiple regions, you can choose the "coracao" as your keywords. Do App Store Optimization, first you should know the rules of app store,only this, you can own a good app.